# Google Compute Engine API: Get object referenced in another object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get the instance group for a given container engine cluster. I can successfully get the container cluster object, and it has a property called `instanceGroupUrls` which is a list of strings where each string is the full URL to an instance group:

```
In [14]: gke_api = discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

In [15]: cluster = gke_api.projects().zones().clusters().get(
    projectId=project_id, zone=zone, clusterId=cluster_id).execute()

In [16]: cluster['instanceGroupUrls']
Out[16]: ['https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project-id}/zones/{zone-id}/instanceGroupManagers/{instanceGroupID}']
```

My question is: How do I get the instance group, given that I only have the full URL to the resource? Now, I could parse that URL and then use the api discovery thing to do `instanceGroups.get(project='foo', instanceGroup='bar')` but that seems very hacky and prone to breakage.

Does the API client has a way to provide the full URL? I have done much googling and poking around in IPython, but couldn't find much. The closest I got was the `HttpRequest` class (http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest-class.html) but I'm not sure what to pass in for the args.

Any help appreciated,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - The discovery for `container` API is independent of the discovery for `compute` API and neither of them can understand the type of the resource using the URL.

- If you just want to view the instance group resource, you can use the [`httplib2.Http`](http://httplib2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libhttplib2.html#http-objects) object authenticated with your credentials to send a request to the URL.
- If you want the flexibility to access the resource using the discovery for `compute` API, like you mentioned you will have to extract the `zone` and `instanceGroupName` fields out of the URL and pass it to [`instanceGroups.get()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.instanceGroups.html#get) . BTW, this is not hacky since the resource format of the URL is very unlikely to change for most Google Cloud APIs. The [instance group API doc is here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceGroups).

## 1. Just viewing the Instance Group resource

If you wish to just view the instance group resource and access its properties without any modifications, you can use an authenticated Http object from `httplib2` to GET the resource corresponding to the URL.

- ### Working Example

  ```
  from googleapiclient import discovery
  from httplib2 import Http
  from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
  import json
  import pprint

  # BEGIN CONFIG
  PRIVATE_KEY_JSON = '/path/to/service_account_credentials.json'
  API_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  PROJECT_NAME = 'some-arbitrary-project'
  ZONE_NAME = 'us-central1-a'
  # END CONFIG

  # Create a ServiceAccountCredentials object by reading the credentials from
  # your JSON file. If you're using a different mechanism to load credentials
  # like Application Default Credentials, substitute building the
  # credentials object accordingly. I've added steps in the very
  # end for using Application Default Credentials.
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      PRIVATE_KEY_JSON, scopes=API_SCOPES)

  # Create an authorized http object which can be used for making the
  # API requests. We will use this later.
  http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

  # Build the Cloud Container Engine API object which you will be using for
  # invoking the corresponding APIs using the authorized Http object
  # you created earlier
  gke_api = discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

  # List all clusters for the specified project and zone
  cluster_list_response = gke_api.projects().zones().clusters().list(
      projectId=PROJECT_NAME, zone=ZONE_NAME).execute()
  # Pick a cluster of interest
  cluster = cluster_list_response['clusters'][0]
  # Pick the instance group of interest
  instance_group_url = cluster['instanceGroupUrls'][0]
  print 'Instance Group URL: ' + instance_group_url

  # Use the authorized Http object to make the request to fetch
  # the instance group resource info.
  response, content = http_auth.request(instance_group_url)
  # Convert the json body into a dict for easy access.
  instance_group = json.loads(content)

  # Display the instance group using pprint.
  print 'Instance Group Info: '
  pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2).pprint(instance_group)
  ```
- ### Output

  ```
  Instance Group URL: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-cluster-foo-some-group

  Instance Group Info:
  { u'baseInstanceName': u'gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-abcdef',
    u'creationTimestamp': u'2017-07-07T10:11:12.678-07:00',
    u'currentActions': { u'abandoning': 0,
                         u'creating': 0,
                         u'creatingWithoutRetries': 0,
                         u'deleting': 0,
                         u'none': 3,
                         u'recreating': 0,
                         u'refreshing': 0,
                         u'restarting': 0},
    u'fingerprint': u'AABBCCDDEFG=',
    u'id': u'12345678901234',
    u'instanceGroup': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroups/gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-some-group',
    u'instanceTemplate': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/global/instanceTemplates/gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-abcdef',
    u'kind': u'compute#instanceGroupManager',
    u'name': u'gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-some-group',
    u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-some-grp',
    u'targetSize': 3,
    u'zone': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a'}
  ```
- ### [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)

  Instead of a service account if you're using Application Default Credentials, you will need to make the following modifications to the above example where you build the credentials object and rest of the code remains the same:

  ```
  from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
  credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  ```

## 2. Extracting the instance group name and using the Compute API

Below is a code snippet (you might need to combine with the snippet I've posted above) for extracting the instance group name and zone name components from the URL. There is no need to extract the project name since it will be the same as the project where you have your Google Container Engine cluster. The output is identical to above.

- ### Snippet to extract the info from URL and invoke Compute Engine API

  ```
  import urlparse

  # Extract the path component of the URL, and using that extract instance group
  # name and zone name.
  instance_group_url_components = urlparse.urlsplit(
      instance_group_url).path.split('/')
  instance_group_name = instance_group_url_components[-1]
  zone_name = instance_group_url_components[-3]

  compute_api = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
  instance_group_info = compute_api.instanceGroups().get(
      project=PROJECT_NAME, zone=zone_name,
      instanceGroup=instance_group_name).execute()

  print 'Instance Group Info: '
  pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2).pprint(instance_group)
  ```
- #### Output

  ```
  Instance Group URL: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-cluster-foo-some-group

  Instance Group Info:
  { u'baseInstanceName': u'gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-abcdef',
    u'creationTimestamp': u'2017-07-07T10:11:12.678-07:00',
    u'currentActions': { u'abandoning': 0,
                         u'creating': 0,
                         u'creatingWithoutRetries': 0,
                         u'deleting': 0,
                         u'none': 3,
                         u'recreating': 0,
                         u'refreshing': 0,
                         u'restarting': 0},
    u'fingerprint': u'AABBCCDDEFG=',
    u'id': u'12345678901234',
    u'instanceGroup': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroups/gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-some-group',
    u'instanceTemplate': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/global/instanceTemplates/gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-abcdef',
    u'kind': u'compute#instanceGroupManager',
    u'name': u'gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-some-group',
    u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-cluster-foo-default-pool-some-grp',
    u'targetSize': 3,
    u'zone': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/some-arbitrary-project/zones/us-central1-a'}
  ```